# Tabs shrinks unexpectedly

Tags: safari

Ventura 13.6.2, Safari 17.1

When there are a lot of tabs, I often see that some of them are shrinks to arbitrary width.

[image]

Notice the 2nd Google tab is narrower than the 1st, whereas the Wikipedia and the 3rd Google tabs are even more narrower. Is it possible to fix somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larger window or fewer tabs.

This is not new or unexpected behaviour.
The current tab is always shown at full size. If you use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>[number]</kbd>  to select a tab,then if the ones near it were already shrunk, only that one tab expands. Those near it stay shrunk. If you click the tab, first it will expand all those near it [& shrink some at the other end of the tab bar to compensate], then the second click will select it.